# Intellisense not working in VSTO app for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I have a VSTO Excel plugin I am creating in Visual Studio 2017.

At the top of the module above all subroutines, I have this line:

```
Public xlApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
```

In several of the subroutines in this same module, I use `xlApp.Activecell.Value` in several places.  As I was originally writing the subs, Intellisense would pop up after typing `xlApp.` and would give me all the expected options.  Something changed, however.

Now when I type `xlApp.` I only see Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, and ToString in the Intellisense. If I type `xlApp.ActiveCell.Value` despite the lack of intellisense, it does not throw a compile or build error, and the app runs as expected although it's much harder to continue writing additional features.

Can anyone direct me as to what I might look for to find the culprit?

I still get the expected Intellisense options when I type `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.` so I know it's still available in the project, but it's like it's not recognizing the "xlApp" alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this statement: **Public xlApp As Excel.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application**

Then when you type xlApp., the member list like the following:
[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was missing!  Thank you so much!